# Apply a mutate over columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have some missing data that I am trying to impute to the mean of each column. My code,

```
apply(train_new, 2, function(x) 
        mutate(
          ifelse(is.na(x) | x < 0, mean(x), x)
        )
)
```

is meant to impute all 17 columns to the mean of each column in one fell swoop, but this returns `Error during wrapup: no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`, and leads me to a debug screen. I'm sure this is just a syntactical issue, but I'm at a loss as to where it is.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(INDEX = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), TARGET_WINS = c(39, 
70, 86, 70, 82, 75), TEAM_BATTING_H = c(1445, 1339, 1377, 1387, 
1297, 1279), TEAM_BATTING_2B = c(194, 219, 232, 209, 186, 200
), TEAM_BATTING_3B = c(39, 22, 35, 38, 27, 36), TEAM_BATTING_HR = c(13, 
190, 137, 96, 102, 92), TEAM_BATTING_BB = c(457.7607, 685, 602, 
451, 472, 443), TEAM_BATTING_SO = c(842, 1075, 917, 922, 920, 
973), TEAM_BASERUN_SB = c(97.288, 37, 46, 43, 49, 107), TEAM_BASERUN_CS = c(NA, 
28, 27, 30, 39, 59), TEAM_PITCHING_H = c(NA, 1347, 1377, 1396, 
1297, 1279), TEAM_PITCHING_HR = c(84, 191, 137, 97, 102, 92), 
TEAM_PITCHING_BB = c(530.9595, 689, 602, 454, 472, 443), 
TEAM_PITCHING_SO = c(737.105, 1082, 917, 928, 920, 973), 
TEAM_FIELDING_E = c(NA, 193, 175, 164, 138, 123), TEAM_FIELDING_DP = c(146.234708045, 
155, 153, 156, 168, 149), TEAM_BATTING_1B = c(1199, 908, 
973, 1044, 982, 951)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

train_new %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.) | . < 0, mean(., na.rm = T), .)))
```

Comment: Does this impute to the mean of each column, or the mean of the entire data frame?

Comment: It calculates the mean of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `na.aggregate` (from `zoo`)

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(replace(train_new, train_new < 0, NA))
```